# Python: Generate random floating point number in a range, excluding start-point

Tags: python, random

`uniform(a,b)` returns values in the range [a,b). How to turn this interval into (a,b)?

Comment: Note that `uniform(a, b)` can generate the upper value `b` too, in many cases.

Comment: It's either `[a,b)` or `(a,b)`. ["The end-point value b may or may not be included in the range depending on floating-point rounding in the equation a + (b-a) * random()."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random.uniform#random.uniform)

Comment: @Phillip: The sentence you quote is correct: `b` may be included. For an extreme example, try `a = 1.0`, `b = 1.0 + 2**-52`. You'll see that `uniform(a, b)` produces `a` half the time and `b` half the time. For a less extreme example, `uniform(1.0, 1.25)` can theoretically generate `1.25`.

Comment: why not continue sampling x=uniform(a,b) until x!=a ?

Comment: Because I didn't want to, of course I should have precised it.

Comment: Its worth noting that after *260 million* trials of sampling `uniform(0,1)` the value of `0` (rounded to 12 places) never showed up, so as @Phillip said in his answer, this case is very unlikely

Comment: Obviously. I'm just being curious here.
@Phillip you posted an answer that seemed pretty neat, but a refresh and it's gone...

Comment: @wnnmaw: You should see `0.0` show up approximately one time in every 2**53 samples. (`random.uniform(0, 1)` essentially returns `n / 2**53`, where `n` is an integer uniformly distributed in the interval `[0, 2**53)`.) So yes, it's unlikely.

Comment: @MarkDickinson No nice solution, then?

Comment: Phillips solution was broken, so he deleted it

Comment: @4hzub: What's wrong with the one wim posted? If you insist, you could do `uniform(next_up(a), next_down(b))`, but you'd have to write the `next_up` and `next_down` functions first (or make use of NumPy's `nexttoward`). I'm not sure I see the point, though.

Comment: Well, if I had wanted to do a test I probably wouldn't have needed seeking advice here, but I will end up accepting it since I guess it is my fault. Your suggestion is more like what I was searching for, thanks, and I was expecting some smart math trick as what Phillip tried. There is absolutely no point, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems simple enough:

```
def my_uniform(a, b):
    while True:
        result = uniform(a, b)
        if a < result < b:
            return result
```